# ui.methods permissions.request in share url

Tags: facebook, user-interface

Earlier today I noticed a friend shared a Viddy video which made me curious. When I clicked on the share link I immediately got an authorization request dialog with custom text on the "next/login" button (Watch the movie).  The URL for this share which triggered the behavior was this:

http://www.facebook.com/
  connect/
    uiserver.php?
    app_id=125119214225766
    method=permissions.request
    redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.viddy.com%2Fvideo%2F2f44f934-bc2f-419f-b462-c46f261744ee
    response_type=code
    display=async
    perms=email%2Cpublish_actions
    auth_referral=1
     fb_private_mode_enc=ASJbi0_rc8L9GhOWGzXF1eZQgqGW6WhIquDadvKiRi8uZRozkFn937vhtfsR_Krg8iM

I've looked around trying to find this feature documented. How am I suppose to generate such share URLs? I found some documentation on fbdevwiki.com, but that does not cover most of the arguments. If anyone could guide me to some documents I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

That's an app using [Authenticated Referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals) so that users are prompted to grant permission directly on Facebook's chrome instead of landing on your app unauthenticated, and then bounced to an auth dialog and back to the app again.

The 'watch video' text in the auth dialog is because this app is publishing 'watch' actions in the [Open Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/video/)

{edit} it appears the 'watch video' link is only shown for preselected partners and isn't available for all video apps
 {/edit}

Answer (score 0):

The generated url you see is generated by the app, you can achieve this by creating your own app and giving it the permission.

You can start by going to [Facebook Developer](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/)